# sqlite connection closes automatically after being unactive for few minutes

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite, database-connection

I have a strange problem with vb.net and sqlite. In my application, if I leave the connection open and dont use my application, for few minutes, it takes long to read or write the database. What could be the reason for this problem? Something to do with con. timeout ?

Comment: Actually im a beginner, so i dont know actually much about that.. could there be any known reasons for this problem?

Comment: Your problem isn't clear, because you aren't giving any debugging results.  You need to give error results, log events, or step through your program to determine what is going on.  I highly recommend reading at least two good texts on how to properly debug a program very early in your programming career (ie, today!) as proper debugging is almost always the easiest way to solve programming difficulties, and is necessary at all levels.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection were closed, you wouldn't be able to use it afterwards.

Windows is known for aggressively swapping out programs, data, and file caches that it thinks might not be used soon.
From your description, this is what seems to have happended.